# JavaScript setting value to variable properties on a function call

Tags: javascript, function, variables, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I found that there are these two ways that a variable property value can be updated on a function call

Example 1:

```js
function bar( arg ) {
  return arg + 1;
}

var foo = {
  num: 1
};

foo.num = bar( foo.num );
console.log( foo.num );
```

Example 2:

```js
function bar( arg ) {
  arg.num = arg.num + 1;
}

var foo = {
  num: 1
};

bar( foo );
console.log( foo.num );
```

I want to know what are the proper naming convention for each of the method calls.

Also can anyone explain, how it is possible to update the original variable value inside a closed function operation as shown in example 2?

Comment: Well it is because objects are passed as reference so you're able to update from a closed function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Primitive parameters (such as a number) are passed to functions by
> value; the value is passed to the function, but if the function
> changes the value of the parameter, this change is not reflected
> globally or in the calling function.
>
> If you pass an object (i.e. a non-primitive value, such as Array or a
> user-defined object) as a parameter and the function changes the
> object's properties, that change is visible outside the function.
> Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Well in javascript `objects` are passed by `reference` so when you pass a object to a function you're passing it's `memory reference` not a `copy`.
So when you update value in the function it updates the value at reference.

```js
function bar(arg) {
  arg.num = arg.num + 1;
}

var foo = {
  num: 1
};

bar(foo);
console.log(foo.num);
```

When you pass a `primitive value` it is passed by `value`. It passes a `copy` of value so whatever changes you do in close function will not affect the original value.

```js
function bar(arg) {
  arg = arg + 1;
}

var foo = 1

bar(foo);
console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know what are the proper naming convention for each of the methods.

There are no naming conventions for *functions* (I would only call them *methods* if they are directly associated to an object), except thar the name is camelCase. However there is a convention in functional programming that functions that return something are *pure* (they do not change anything, but just return something new, like your first function), and functions that return nothing are *impure*, they change something. Wether you strictly follow that pattern depends on your codingstyle, I follow that often but not always. It is also a bit harder in JS as JS is not typed.

> also can anyone explain, how it is possible to update the original variable value inside a closed function operation as shown in example 2?

It is impossible. If you pass a number, it is passed as a value, you have no way to find out where that number belongs to. Thats a good thing as you can always keep track which function is able to mutate an object. `bar(foo)` is, `bar(foo.num)` is not.